# How to insert only one return code in JavaScript function with if statement?

Tags: javascript, function, return, alert

I am trying to learn JavaScript and I wrote a function, that works as an easy calculator. It works OK, but I think there must be a way how to write only one return line of code. Any ideas how to simplify my code? (Without actually rewriting it all :)
Thank you for you help!
Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Only one thing changes; the string passed to `alert`. Build the string. Call `alert` only once.

Comment: Well, you could remove all of the `return` keywords entirely, since [`alert()` doesn't return anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) and therefore neither does your function.

Comment: Remove each of the `return` lines and after the `if`, but before the function ends, add `return result` if that's what you want. Or if you only want the `alert` then instead write `alert(result)`.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I will certainly  use Code Reviews and avoid pictures.  This was my first use of function in JavaScript and Alert, it is a part of my learning course, so I see why you see no point in this, but is is for educational purposes only :)

Answer (score -1):

There is **no** point in using `return` in the first place, i would use switch case instead of all these messy if else statements.

```
switch (operator) {
   case '+':
      alert(`Your result is ${number1 + number2}`);
      break;
   case '-':
      alert(`Your result is ${number1 - number2}`);
      break;
   // and so on
}
```

Comment: Surely there is a point in using `return`... you don't want the function to return undefined here.

Comment: @trincot it was returning undefined before, rewriting it like this doesn't change that.

Comment: @Barmar, surely you know I know that, but why not help the asker?

Comment: @trincot this function doesn't need to return anything at all (also called void function), is there any point I'm missing ?

Comment: Well, I think we would agree that using `alert` is not user friendly for anything that deserves the name calculator. I feel it is better practice to return values and have the I/O managed elsewhere (separation of concern) and in a different way (using HTML document, or whatever UI there is)

Comment: @trincot I agree, but I guess the point is just displaying the output rather than being user friendly.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. This was my first use of function in JavaScript and Alert, it is a part of my learning course, so I see why you see no point in this, but is is for educational purposes only :) I am looking forward to writing functions, that will be more practical and less undefined :)

Answer (score -1):

```
let result = 0

if (operator === '+') result = number1 + number2
else if (operator === '-') result = number1 - number 2

alert(result)
```

Or use a switch

```
result = 0

switch (operator):
    case '+':
        result = number1 + number2
        break
    case '-':
        result = number1 - number2

alert(result)
```

If your function doesn't need to return any value just just `alert` without `return`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I haven't ever seen "switch" before and everybody seems to recommend. I am going to google that up, so that I understand your advice!